# .csproj file is missing while checkin the pending changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, checkin, vcs-checkout

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 with Team Foundation Server 2010. Everything was fine with the check in and check out. Now I am stuck with a problem. The problem is `.csproj` file is missing while showing the pending changes. Because of this when I check in any `.cs` file it is not updated in server. Can anyone say me in what way I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you should do is install [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).  My suspicion from what you've said is that the `csproj` file is not under source control, and the easiest way to get it in is via power tools.

In order to validate that this is the case, open the source control explorer and look in your repository for the csproj file.  My guess is that you won't find it.  If you don't then navigate to it in explorer, right click and select add to source control.

(You can do this without power tools, just select add files and navigate to it)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then found the .csproj under "Excluded changes" via the "Detected xx add(s)" link. I could "promote" it so it got visible in the "Included changes".